# What was the movie playing in Sherlock (The Final Problem)?

Tags: sherlock

At the beginning of Sherlock's finale (*The Final Problem*), Mycroft Holmes was watching a classic movie. Could you please recognize it? What is the movie's name?

[image]

Comment: Per Walts answer I know it's not, but I swear that woman is a carbon copy of Famke Janssen as phoenix (Jean Grey). https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bHC0oOkRfog/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: I'm pretty sure that movie was supposed to be a hidden message and part of the show. I don't quite remember for sure.

Comment: As the answer says it's not a real movie, but it's meant to look like a Dick Tracy-style detective movie.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**It's not a real film**. It's a fictional 'classic' noir film made for this show. If you look them up on IMDb, the actors playing ['Leonard'](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm2270215/) and ['Velma'](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3597163/) in that movie are contemporary actors and started acting in 2004 and 2006, respectively (and they don't play these characters anywhere else).